# ¿Cómo puedo hacer un filtro para evitar valores repetidos dentro de una lista?

Tags: python

Trato de realizar un filtro para evitar que diversos resultados de una operación con valores absolutos se repitan en una lista.
El filtro es el siguiente:

```
if str(sol) not in str(result):
```

Donde:

```
  #result es la lista donde se almacenan los resultados de la variable sol 
  result = []

  #Son las variables definidas de las expresiones regulares  
  x, y , z = -3, -5, 8 

  #Estas variables toman una expresión regular de un diccionario repleto de expresiones regulares, view_expr es la expresión regular estética y expr es la expresión regular a evaluar
  view_expr, expr = choice(list(fmts.items())) 
  expr = expr.format(x,y,z)

  # Sol evalua las expresiones regulares
  sol = eval(expr)
```

Hasta ahora todo esto no me genera ningún error lógico ni de sintáxis. El problema es que al realizar las iteraciones con dicho filtro, me arroja un número limitado de valores que no están en la lista `result`. Es decir, de 500 iteraciones que realizo me arroja entre 12-14 resultados sin repetir, si aumento el número de iteraciones, es el mismo número que me arroja, entre 12 - 14 resultados sin repetir, a lo que me lleva a deducir que algo está mal con el filtro.

Aquí dejo el códgio entero por si gustan verlo, no lo anoto dentro de la pregunta porque considero que no es necesario, debido a la mínima cantidad de código necesaria: https://pastebin.com/1S35HHbD

¿Alguien puede ayudarme a resolver este problema? De antemano agradezco mucho su apoyo, muchas gracias.

Comment: Me parece que el problema principal es que estás utilizando la colección equivocada... una lista acepta cualquier valor, repetido las veces que sea... un set no acepta valores repetidos, no necesitas filtrarlo ni hacer nada a mayores, porque si intentas meter dos veces el mismo valor en un set, no entra más que una.

Comment: Si hago un set, ¿cómo podría decirle al programa que no imprima la operación estética de la variable `view_expr`? Es decir, la variable `expr` no se va a repetir dentro del set, pero la otra variable sí lo hará porque no está dentro de ese set

Comment: Otro problema que tendría es que set no tiene un índice, por lo tanto no podría contabilizar los elementos del set y por lo tanto, no podría iterar la cantidad de elementos que hay dentro del set al momento de guardar en un archivo txt los resultados

Comment: Hice una prueba rápida con tu código cuando haces `if str(sol) not in str(result):` conviertes tanto `sol` como toda la lista en un `string,` y luego comparas si existe sol dentro de result, cuando por ejemplo `sol` vale `13` digamos que se agrega a `result` pero si luego `sol` vale `3` al convertir `result` en un solo `string` entonces el `3` ya existe, porque era parte del `13`

Comment: Nota: siempre es mejor poner el código completo en la pregunta ya que los enlaces externos podrían dejar de funcionar, además parte de lo que puse en la respuesta se relaciona con tu código pero no es visible en lo que está en la pregunta, si el enlace externo deja de funcionar entonces otros usuarios no entenderían de que estamos hablando, te recomiendo que edites la pregunta y agregues el código externo para mantener toda la información en [es.so].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Buen día,

Como puse en los comentarios el problema se origina por esta línea:

```
if str(sol) not in str(result):
```

Originalmente `result` es una lista, por ejemplo:

```
[1, 2, 3]
```

Pero al hacer `str(result)` lo que obtienes es un único `string`, por ejemplo:

```
"[1, 2, 3]"
```

Entonces al intentar resolver el `if` como lo pusiste, `Python` lo interpreta como buscar un `substring` en un `string`, ejemplo:

Supongamos que `result` tiene los siguientes elementos:

```
[10, 13, 125]
```

Si lo interpretas como un solo string, es decir `"[10, 13, 125]"`, entonces cuando `sol` obtenga por ejemplo `"3"` ó `"25"` o incluso `2`  verá que ya existe porque son parte de `13` y `125` respectivamente y por lo tanto no se agregarán a la lista de `result`.

Parte del problema es porque al agregar los elementos a `result` lo haces de la siguiente forma:

```
result.append(f'{sol}\n')
```

Lo que yo haría es agregar directamente los valores numéricos, así:

```
result.append(sol)
```

De esta forma el `if` en cuestión quedaría así:

```
if sol not in result:
```

Y al escribir `result` en tu archivo lo puedes cambiar de esta forma:

```
archivo.write(f'{result[i]\n}')
```

Comment: Ok, muchas gracias, ya lo intenté y sigue el mismo problema, pero creo que este no es un problema. Me explico, al tener una cantidad definida de expresiones regulares y tres valores para las variables `x`, `y`, `z` ya definidos, las combinaciones al evaluarse éstos valores están prefedinidos a ser evaluados. Como hay una gran posibilidad de obtener la misma cantidad de ciertos números, éstos se repiten con mayor frecuencia y al definir una cantidad de iteraciones, supongamos 3000, no habrá mucha diferencia que realizar 500 iteraciones

Comment: Es decir, si tienes estas variables como valores `x, y , z = -3, -5, 8`, la suma, multiplicación o resta es muy probable que sea 15, 13, 8, 2, -11, 24, 40, -3, -5, -13, -2, -8. Y si quiero que se aumente el mayor número de elementos, tengo que hacer iteraciones superiores a las 50 mil, en un punto, llegará que no se pueden hacer más combinaciones y por lo tanto, no van a salir valores diferentes superiores a los 12-14 elementos en dicha lista, porque la condición es no repetirse.

Comment: Si, es correcto, pero al hacer la prueba con el código original no se registraba por ejemplo el `3` si anteriormente ya existía el `13`, eso era un error en el código.

Comment: Oh, no lo había notado, deja checarlo, agradezco bastante ese detalle, gracias!